# OracleXE Service OracleXETNSListener won't start

Tags: oracle, oracle-xe

I'm trying to run oracleXE in my computer. However, I can't get the `OracleXETNSListener` to start.
I've tryed to remove the `ORACLE_HOME` variable, and this fixes the problem. However, when I do delete te `ORACLE_HOME` variable and open the SQL command line (otherwise it won't open) when I try to login using SYSTEM user I can't because this variable is missing